# Build a Swift project in CLion

Tags: swift, build, clion

I am trying to build a simple project in CLion 2016.1, Swift plugin.

I followed instructions here http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/swift-plugin-for-clion/ and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5326

When I try to build the CLion project, it gives me:
`error: no Package.swift file found`

Shouldn't that be handled by CLion? What is a correct configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CLion uses Swift build system I had to set up a Swift package like described here: https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-build-system

The structure must be the following:

```
 - Package.swift
 - Sources
 - - - main.swift
```

After that `swift build` worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your *CMakeLists.txt* should look something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(HelloWorld)

add_custom_target(HelloWorld
        COMMAND swift build
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        SOURCES Package.swift Sources/main.swift)
```